# Excel- поиск максимального значения ячейки на нескольких листах и подстановка соответствующего этому значению времени из соседней ячейки

Tags: excel, index, match

Есть 12 листов в книге Excel, на каждом - таблица типа значение|время. На отдельном листе задана формула нахождения максимального значения из всех 12 листов в виде
`=МАКС(Январь:Декабрь!A2)`
Для этого максимального значения нужно подобрать соответсвующее ему время из соседней ячейки. Проблема в том, что моя формула не ищет соответствующее время, если задать диапазон листов как в формуле максимального значения
`=ИНДЕКС(Январь:Декабрь!B2;ПОИСКПОЗ(МАКСА(Январь:Декабрь!A2);Январь:Декабрь!A2;0))`

Есть ли другой способ вытащить это соответсвующее время на отдельный лист?

Answer (score 0):

С трехмерными ссылками (лист-столбец-строка) работают немногие функции.

В *Excel* сутки = 1 (24/24). Время - часть суток, число <1. Например, 2 часа = 2/24, 23 часа = 23/24... Это можно использовать в простом решении.

В свободной ячейке на 12 листах (например, `C2`) суммируем:

```
=A2+B2
```

Это для случая, когда значения в `A2` по модулю всегда >=1.

В результате получим число, целая часть которого - значение из `A2`, дробная - время из `B2`. Т.е. на листе с наибольшим значением в `A2` в ячейке `C2` тоже будет наибольшее из всех сумм.

На отдельном листе, где вычисляется наибольшее из всех `A2`:

```
=МАКС(Январь:Декабрь!С2)-наибольшее_среди_всех_A2
```

Если время указано >24 часов (к примеру, 38:25), т.е. больше суток, или значение в `A2`<1 (к примеру, 0.82)  - не страшно, достаточно в формуле сделать `A2>B2. Типа такого:

```
=A2*100+B2/10
```

При этом не забыть добавить в формулу на отдельном листе соответствующие доп. вычисления.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант, он конечно более ресурсоемкий и наверно при большом количестве данных будет работать медленнее, но более универсальный:
Склеиваем значения и время в одну строку с разделителями, затем ищем в этой строке наше максимальное значение и вырезаем соответствующее ему время.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По порядку:

1. Объединяем значения используя разделитель ^

`C2: =СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^")`

2. Ищем в полученной строке наше максимальное значение

`D2: =ПОИСК(СЦЕПИТЬ("^";A2;"^");C2)`

3. Ищем первый символ времени, соответствующий найденному значению

`E2: =ПОИСК("^";C2;D2+1)`

4. Ищем последний символ времени

`F2: =ПОИСК("^";C2;E2+1)`

5. Вырезаем найденное значение

`G2: =ПСТР(C2;E2+1;F2-E2-1)`

6. Преобразуем найденное значение в число, и форматируем его как время

`H2: =ЗНАЧЕН(G2)`

Подставляя все это в одну формулу, получаем такую монстрообразную функцию:

`B2: =ЗНАЧЕН(ПСТР(СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^");ПОИСК("^";СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^");ПОИСК(СЦЕПИТЬ("^";A2;"^");СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^"))+1)+1;ПОИСК("^";СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^");ПОИСК("^";СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^");ПОИСК(СЦЕПИТЬ("^";A2;"^");СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^"))+1)+1)-ПОИСК("^";СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^");ПОИСК(СЦЕПИТЬ("^";A2;"^");СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^"))+1)-1))`

Плюсы такого решения в независимости от данных, значения могут быть любыми (положительными, отрицательными, целыми и дробными), искомое время может тоже быть любым включая и дату+время и даже простой текст (тут только надо выбирать разделитель, который не может быть в тексте). И не требуется создавать дополнительные формулы в каждом листе.

Дополнительно, можно получить и номер листа (месяца) где это значение найдено

Получаем всю строку с начала до искомого значения

`I2: =ЛЕВСИМВ(C2;F2-1)`

Считаем сколько в ней встречается символов разделителя (по 2 на каждую пару значение/время) и поделив на 2, получаем номер листа, где это значение найдено

`J2: =(ДЛСТР(I2)-ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(I2;"^";"")))/2`

**Уважаемый @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA предложил более оптимальный вариант:**

Пункты 2-6 заменяем одной формулой:

`D2: =--ПСТР(C2;ПОИСК(A2;C2)+ДЛСТР(A2)+1;ПОИСК("^";ПСТР(C2;ПОИСК(A2;C2)+ДЛСТР(A2)+1;99))-1)`

Итого общая формула будет выглядеть так:

`=--ПСТР(СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^");ПОИСК(A2;СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^"))+ДЛСТР(A2)+1;ПОИСК("^";ПСТР(СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^");ПОИСК(A2;СЦЕПИТЬ("^";Январь!A2;"^";Январь!B2;"^";Февраль!A2;"^";Февраль!B2;"^";Март!A2;"^";Март!B2;"^";Апрель!A2;"^";Апрель!B2;"^";Май!A2;"^";Май!B2;"^";Июнь!A2;"^";Июнь!B2;"^";Июль!A2;"^";Июль!B2;"^";Август!A2;"^";Август!B2;"^";Сентябрь!A2;"^";Сентябрь!B2;"^";Октябрь!A2;"^";Октябрь!B2;"^";Ноябрь!A2;"^";Ноябрь!B2;"^";Декабрь!A2;"^";Декабрь!B2;"^"))+ДЛСТР(A2)+1;99))-1)`

Так формула в 2 раза короче

Comment: 1. Объединяем значения в C2. Пункт 2 и все, что ниже, заменяем одной формулой: `=--ПСТР(C2;ПОИСК(A2;C2);ПОИСК("^";ПСТР(C2;ПОИСК(A2;C2);99))-1)`. Если результат нужен текстовый, то убрать двойное отрицание

Comment: @vikttur-stop-ru-war-in-ua не совсем понял Ваш комментарий, что имелось в ввиду?

Comment: Извините, ошибся. Формула возвращает значение, которое уже найдено :) Чтобы вернуть время, которое относится к максимальному значению, нужно  допилить формулу: `=--ПСТР(C2;ПОИСК(A2;C2)+ДЛСТР(A2)+1;ПОИСК("^";ПСТР(C2;ПОИСК(A2;C2)+ДЛСТР(A2)+1;99))-1)`

Comment: @vikttur-stop-ru-war-in-ua Спасибо, теперь оно, а то всю голову сломал, выводило само значение а не время. Сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Зачем сцеплять? Неужто на листе не найдется  свободной ячейки для сцепки значений и второй свободной - для времени?

Comment: Может конечно и найдется, я не знаю, какая у автора вопроса задача, может он добавлять столбцы или нет, потому и расписывал подробно, если может конечно лучше из двух столбцов, так оно намного понятнее, если нет, то все сводится, пусть и не очень понятной, но одной формуле